# как узнать есть ли \0 в строке?

Tags: c

во время выполнения кода происходит утечка памяти, работаю я со строками, поэтому подозреваю, что где-то не стоит \0 в конце строки, каким образом можно проверить, есть ли он в строке?

Comment: Где-то он в любом случае есть :) А вот в пределах ли выделенной памяти или нет...

Comment: Можно и не проверять, а просто принудительно записывать 0 в последний байт буфера. "Испортить" строку при этом невозможно, т. к. последний байт либо и так будет (должен быть) равен 0, либо (если строка короче буфера и 0 стоит где-то раньше) вообще не используется. Ну а проверить можно с помощью функции `strnlen_s` (появилась в C11), которая, в отличие от `strlen`, не выйдет за границу буфера при отсутствии 0.

Answer (score 1):

Символ `\0` как раз обозначает рамки строки, так что, думаю, если заранее неизвестна длина строки, то узнать, есть ли в ней этот символ или нет, невозможно.

Если же длина проверяемой строки известна, попробуйте её просто пройти в цикле:

```
// L - длина
for (int i = 0: i < L; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == '\0') {
        /* ура, такой символ есть */
    }
}
```

Comment: Речь идет о C. А там 0 является признаком конца строки. Он не может быть где-то посередине строки.

Comment: Хоть это и на грани фола из-за чтения за пределами выделенной памяти, но я бы пользовал что-то типа `assert(strlen(str) < L)`...

Comment: Да ваще решение такого вопроса про `\0` в Си в любом случае каким-то бредом обернётся